# Simple menu. CSS not working in IE7

Tags: html, css

I have the following menu. Seems to work in all browser but not IE6 or IE7. What is causing the problem and How can i fix that.

**Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/2ysCC/**

```
#menu_wrap {
    margin-top:20px auto 0 auto;
    padding:0;
    width:780px;
    height:40px;
    list-style-type:none;
}
.button a {
    cursor:pointer;
    text-align:center;
    font:13px/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    position:relative;
    min-width:50px;
    height:20px;
    float:left;
    padding:10px;
    padding-right:0;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.Red, .Red .button a {
    color:#faddde;
    background: #ed1c24;
}
.button:last-child a {
    float:left;
    border:none;
}

<ul id="menu_wrap" class="Red">
  <li class="button"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li class="button"><a href="#">portfolio</a></li>
  <li class="button"><a href="#">Latest</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is how it looks in IE7
[image]

Comment: @fix I added a screenshot above. This is how it appears in IE7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add 'display: inline;' to your 'li'.

```
#menu_wrap .button {
  display: inline;
}
```

Here is an article describing the bug in further detail: http://css-tricks.com/501-prevent-menu-stepdown/

Comment: #menuwrap needs to be "#menu_wrap" (with an underscore).

Answer (score 1):

Float the li tags instead of the a tags:

```
.button {
   float: left;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ysCC/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `position: relative` and make it `float: left`

Comment: Sorry, didn\t see the `float: left` in your code... Just try to remove the relative

Comment: Did you try that in IE7. I removed position relative. and i already have float left. It's not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS, float left element `<LI>`

```
li.button{
  float: left;    
}
```